# Minimize the space widgets fill in a QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qgridlayout

Below is a picture of my `QDockWidget`, which has a `QFrame`, and this `QFrame` has a `QGridLayout`. The single row I have in this layout places itself in the middle, but I'd like it to just sit neatly at the top instead.

Does `QGridLayout` have any methods for its widgets to fill as little space as possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertically expanding [spacer-item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspaceritem.html) to the bottom of the grid-layout, so that it pushes the widgets above it to the top.